# How to install Viber on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, viber

I installed Viber from the downloaded `viber.deb` executables but it gets uninstalled when I do the next update. From reading other posts I know there is something screwed up here. I tried following other instruction but the result is the same- Ubuntu update removes Viber.

Does anyone have a working method for installing Viber on 18.04.

At least now it  seems like the zoom has been fixed and it is no longer necessary to go into the SQlite database.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: This is NOT unclear. anyone tried updating Viber on 18.04 knows what he is talking about. Viber devs are lazy and do not want to change the lib version in the DEB. So you have to do it manually in order to install Viber.

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, the Viber developers are pretty lazy. But the fix is very easy.

1. download the viber.deb file (http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb)
2. unpack the .deb file with the default Ubuntu packing
   manager (dpkg)
3. fix the dependancy in the control file
4. pack a new .deb file and install it

So in code:

```
dpkg-deb -x viber.deb viber 
dpkg-deb --control viber.deb viber/DEBIAN

vim viber/DEBIAN/control
```

repace "libcurl3" with "libcurl4". Also remove the last empty line in the file if it gets added by vim.

```
dpkg -b viber vibernew.deb
sudo dpkg -i vibernew.deb
```

Done. Don't forget to delete all the made up directories:

```
rm viber.deb; rm viber -rf
```

Comment: Hi, guys. I can also confirm that these instructions work. Thank you, Gy Tis. I thought the problem was self-evident and no detailed description was needed.